# How to kill the debugger process and fix the scrollbar in Intellij IDEA

Tags: debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have tried two versions of IDEA, one is 2016.3, and the other one is 2017.2.And I have two problems in both of them.

1.When I stop the tomcat7 in IDEA, the debugger is still running even if I enabled the "Kill the debug process immediately" configuration, so if I rerun tomcat in debug mode, it tells me the port of debugger(1099) is in use.How can I kill the debugger when I stop the tomcat?

2.Sometimes, when I drag the scrollbar in editor, it will back to the original position.I have to drag it one more time to fix it. Anyone else has this problem?

Comment: Your first problem has nothing to do with IntelliJ IDEA, your app probably creates threads that are not shut down properly and Tomcat server can't stop using the default shutdown script. Try with some other app to verify if it's the case. The second problem should be reported as a bug with your environment details and the steps to reproduce at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: Thank you very much,CrazyCoder. I reported it, but it was not solved well.Then I reinstalled my OS, both of the two problems are solved. So, I think the problem was on my OS actually.Thanks again!